# confidence intervals for cox proportional hazards with 0 events in one treatment arm

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, cox-model, robust

We are performing a multivariate cox proportional hazards analysis with 6 covariates. Two of the covariates (Pre_ASCT_response2 and NGS_graft_MRD2) are binary covariates with 0 events in one condition. Because of this the standard coxph analysis in R does not give standard errors for these covariates and the confidence intervals are from 0 to infinity (see f1 below). We have noticed that setting robust=TRUE we can get 'robust' estimates for the SE, but in this case the estimates are far too small and the confidence intervals are too narrow (see f2 below). Hence we have two unsatisfactory fits.

Does anybody know how to find reasonable estimates of SE for coefficients in cox prop hazards if there are 0 events in one condition of a binary covariate?

The kind of thing we are hoping to find would be the 'cox ph equivalent' of the Wilson Interval for binomial proportions confidence intervals.

If there is no such method, then can we add a 'pseudo-event' to the condition with 0 events so that we avoid the infinite hazard? Is there a reasonable way to add such an event and still perform a multivariate analysis?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

> summary(f2)
>   Call:
>   coxph(formula = os ~ Sex + Age2 + ISS2 + Pre_ASCT_response2 + 
>       NGS_graft_MRD2 + maintenance_1, data = df1, robust = TRUE)
>
> n= 87, number of events= 9 
>      (11 observations deleted due to missingness)
>
> ```
>                          coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)  robust se      z Pr(>|z|)    
> Sex                -4.303e-01  6.503e-01  7.200e-01  6.339e-01 -0.679   0.4973    
> Age2                1.707e-01  1.186e+00  7.399e-01  7.540e-01  0.226   0.8209    
> ISS2                6.957e-01  2.005e+00  3.591e-01  3.363e-01  2.068   0.0386 *  
> Pre_ASCT_response2  9.522e+00  1.366e+04  8.111e+03  3.467e-01 27.468   <2e-16 ***
> NGS_graft_MRD2      1.930e+01  2.400e+08  1.457e+04  6.670e-01 28.929   <2e-16 ***
> maintenance_1       5.909e-01  1.806e+00  7.037e-01  6.502e-01  0.909   0.3634    
>
>                    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
> Sex                6.503e-01  1.538e+00 1.877e-01 2.253e+00
> Age2               1.186e+00  8.430e-01 2.706e-01 5.199e+00
> ISS2               2.005e+00  4.987e-01 1.037e+00 3.876e+00
> Pre_ASCT_response2 1.366e+04  7.321e-05 6.924e+03 2.695e+04
> NGS_graft_MRD2     2.400e+08  4.166e-09 6.493e+07 8.872e+08
> maintenance_1      1.806e+00  5.538e-01 5.049e-01 6.458e+00
>
> Concordance= 0.81  (se = 0.113 )
> Rsquare= 0.123   (max possible= 0.524 )
> Likelihood ratio test= 11.43  on 6 df,   p=0.07604
> Wald test            = 2607  on 6 df,   p=0
> Score (logrank) test = 10.86  on 6 df,   p=0.09293,   Robust = 8.15  p=0.2272
> ```
>
> summary(f1)
>   Call:
>   coxph(formula = os ~ Sex + Age2 + ISS2 + Pre_ASCT_response2 + 
>       NGS_graft_MRD2 + maintenance_1, data = df1, robust = FALSE)
>
> n= 87, number of events= 9 
>      (11 observations deleted due to missingness)
>
> ```
>                          coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
> Sex                -4.303e-01  6.503e-01  7.200e-01 -0.598   0.5501  
> Age2                1.707e-01  1.186e+00  7.399e-01  0.231   0.8175  
> ISS2                6.957e-01  2.005e+00  3.591e-01  1.937   0.0527 .
> Pre_ASCT_response2  9.522e+00  1.366e+04  8.111e+03  0.001   0.9991  
> NGS_graft_MRD2      1.930e+01  2.400e+08  1.457e+04  0.001   0.9989  
> maintenance_1       5.909e-01  1.806e+00  7.037e-01  0.840   0.4011  
>
>                    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
> Sex                6.503e-01  1.538e+00    0.1586     2.667
> Age2               1.186e+00  8.430e-01    0.2782     5.058
> ISS2               2.005e+00  4.987e-01    0.9918     4.053
> Pre_ASCT_response2 1.366e+04  7.321e-05    0.0000       Inf
> NGS_graft_MRD2     2.400e+08  4.166e-09    0.0000       Inf
> maintenance_1      1.806e+00  5.538e-01    0.4546     7.171
>
> Concordance= 0.81  (se = 0.113 )
> Rsquare= 0.123   (max possible= 0.524 )
> Likelihood ratio test= 11.43  on 6 df,   p=0.07604
> Wald test            = 4.69  on 6 df,   p=0.5838
> Score (logrank) test = 10.86  on 6 df,   p=0.09293
> ```

Comment: This is ultimately a form of separation. You might try reading the threads categorized under the [tag:hauck-donner-effect].

Comment: Have you looked at Firth's penalized (partial) likelihood approach as implemented e.g. in SAS? There's a paper on it "A solution to the issue of separation on Cox regression" (or some similar name) by (I think) Schemper et al.

Comment: Thanks!  I am now using the R package ‘coxphf’ which implements Firth's penalized (partial) likelihood. It works well